# Set flex row height to fit child img size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a flexbox row to match it's height to a child img, which height is set by its width (from CSS) and its ratio (from file). 
Is there a pure-CSS way to achieve this behavior?

```css
.row {
  width: 50%; 
  height: auto; /* does not work */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.row, .row > * {
  background: rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.row > .text {
  white-space: normal;
  flex-grow: 2; /* width: 100%  also works */
}

.row > img:last-child {
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="text">Some text content, occupies all available space.<br/>Image to the right should have 4x3 ratio</div>
  <img src="https://www.christart.com/IMAGES-art9ab/clipart/5233/blown-leaves-background.jpg"><!-- a random 4x3 image from Internet -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to change [the alignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) because by default it's `stretch`

```css
.row {
  width: 50%; 
  display: flex;
  align-items:flex-start; /*added this*/
  flex-direction: row;
}

.row, .row > * {
  background: rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.row > .text {
  white-space: normal;
  flex-grow: 2; /* width: 100%  also works */
}

.row > img:last-child {
  width: 40%;
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="text">Some text content, occupies all available space.<br/>Image to the right should have 4x3 ratio</div>
  <img src="https://www.christart.com/IMAGES-art9ab/clipart/5233/blown-leaves-background.jpg"><!-- a random 4x3 image from Internet -->
</div>
```